# Assigning a depth to each node

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

I read a few other articles on here that looked similar, but didn't quite answer my problem. I've been given a question for an assignment to assign every node in a binary tree its respective depth. I just can't quite get it.

For reference this is my code:

```
struct treeNode {
   int item;
   int depth;
   treeNode *left;
   treeNode *right;
};
typedef treeNode *Tree;

int assignDepth(Tree &T, int depth)
{
    if(T!=NULL)
    {
        depth = assignDepth(T->left, depth++);
        T->depth = depth;
        depth = assignDepth(T->right, depth++);
    }
    else //leaf
        return depth--;
}
```

I tried running it through with pen and paper and it looked OK, but my desk checking skills are clearly lacking.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please? This is my first time using trees, and recursion isn't my strong point.

Answer:

```
void treecoords(Tree &T, int depth)
{
    static int count = -1; //set to -1 so the precrement before assignment doesn't give the wrong values
    if(T!=NULL)
    {
        treecoords(T->left, depth+1); //depth decrements automatically once this function call is removed from the stack
        count++;
        T->x = count;
          T->y = depth;
        treecoords(T->right, depth+1);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered my post. I understand I was thinking about it all wrong now. I'll go away and try to fix the code given what you've told me and post my final results. I don't want to just use someones code without fully understanding it (though I do appreciate that you've posted it for me, thanks).

Comment: It works! I made a recursive algorithm which ended up matching Mr. Cooper's. It's actually part of a larger algorithm which assigns x and y coordinates to tree nodes. The algorithm is in the original question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  don' t need

```
else //leaf
    return depth--;
```

You also don't want to increment the depth variable, just pass depth+1 to the next interation.

Also there's no need to return a value.

Try this:

```
void assignDepth(Tree T, int depth)
{
    if(T!=NULL)
    {
        assignDepth(T->left, depth+1);
        T->depth = depth;
        assignDepth(T->right, depth+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why not, but everyone has said to remove it, so I did. Recursion breaks my mind. Thanks :)

Comment: It helps to think through what's happening.  In the first call depth = 0 (or whatever) and T is the root of the tree.  Assuming T is not NULL the function calls itself on the left sub-tree with depth+1, assigns depth to the current (root) node, then calls itself on the right sub-tree, again with depth+1.  It's that middle step that assigns the value of the depth parameter to the node, so there's no need to return the value to anywhere.

Comment: That makes sense. I get a little confused with value returning in recursion. But I think I get it now. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, you're using post-increment/decrement, you probably meant `++depth/--depth` for the right assignment and the else return;

Also, why pass a pointer as a reference variable?

Comment: I tried the precrement as you suggested and it's getting there, but not quite right. Why would I use precrement instead of post? I thought that only mattered in order of operations?

I'm using the reference to a pointer because that's how it seems to work. We were given very brief introductions to pointers, then dropped in an ocean of Trees. It was very much a guess and check to see when the compiler stopped throwing errors at me.

Answer (score 1):

```
int assignDepth(Tree &T, int depth)
```

You have defined `Tree` as a pointer to a `treeNode`. You don't need to pass it by reference. You can modify the node that's pointed to anyway.

```
{
    if(T!=NULL)
    {
        depth = assignDepth(T->left, depth++);
```

The postfix `++` ensures that you're passing the original `depth` down. That's not what you want. Increment `depth` before this, and forget about returning it as a function result.

```
    T->depth = depth;
```

This is OK.

```
        depth = assignDepth(T->right, depth++);
```

Similar as for the previous recursive call, except that here you shouldn't modify `depth` at all because it has already been incremented.

```
    }
  else //leaf
        return depth--;
```

You don't need to return any depth information (or is that an unstated requirement?).

```
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I read all the comments to make sure I don't miss anything. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Once you've reached a leaf node, you don't care about its depth any more, so the return value appears to accomplish nothing.
2. In two statements:

   ```
   depth = assignDepth(T->left, depth++);
   // and
   depth = assignDepth(T->right, depth++);
   ```

You have undefined behavior from modifying `depth` twice without an intervening sequence point (although it seems like there should be, there is *not* a sequence point between the right and left sides of an assignment).

Comment: I just realized why the return value is redundant as I was typing this. Man do I feel stupid. Thanks :)!

Not sure what sequence points are, sorry.

Comment: @user475234: I debated over even mentioning it, since fixing the code otherwise will remove this problem as well. With a few exception, C basically says you can only modify a particular variable once in a given statement, and in this case you're doing it twice (once in the increment, once in the assignment).

Answer (score 1):

1. Why are you returning when the node is NULL. As per your specification you don't need to return any depth
2. In other case you just need to increment the depth and send to the function call. The following is my version of the code

   void assignDepth(Tree &T,int depth)
   {
       if(T == NULL)
           return;
       else
       {
           T->depth = depth;
           if(T->left != NULL) assignDepth(T->left,depth+1);
           if(T->right != NULL) assignDepth(T->right,depth+1);
       }
   }

Comment: It's starting to make a little more sense. I realize now that when the recursion is finished it doesn't need to return the depth, because as it pulls the function call off the stack, depth is the same value it was before you called the function. Thanks :D!

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly more complicated design with varying Node Types and did this, so i thought id share.

If you have a tree that varies in type Node to Node (Binary, Unary etc) it is worth simplifying the traditional method to avoid the nasty embedded IFs to check the Nodes type.

**Two Functions:**

- 1: From the root, run through each node and check its distance to the
  root by recursivly calling itself and adding 1 for each parent. Give
  each node a depth variable to store this.
- 2: From the complete set of    Nodes in the tree run a MAX check
  against each nodes depth, the    highest number will equal the depth
  of the tree.

Processing this way removes explicit type-checking and simply counts the Node no matter if it has one, two or a hundred children.

Hope this helps someone!